# Connection reset by peer + browser based upload youtube video

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to do Browser-based upload from android. In the first steps, the mobile asks my server to get a url and token from youtube. after the mobile got if from the server, the mobile uploads the video to youtube. But sometimes a "Connection Reset By Peer" exception is thrown, after the video was uploaded and can be seen on youtube. How can I avoid this error, or at least check if the video was uploaded correctly? 
and another thing, I don't get the youtube_VideoId in the response (in the case there is no exception).

this is the code for the uploading step:

```
   File file = new File(fileName);
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String postURL =  url + "?nexturl=http://example.com";
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
        FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("email", new StringBody("XXX@gmail.com", "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        reqEntity.addPart("token", new StringBody(token));
        reqEntity.addPart("uploadfile", bin);
        this.totalSize = bin.getContentLength();
        post.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection reset maybe a happening if there are really long videos. I know there was a bug open for more than an hour connections.

You can check [YouTube direct Lite for Android](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/blob/master/src/com/google/ytdl/ResumableUpload.java#L259) project to poll about video status and processing status.

Comment: It happens after about 5 minutes, after the whole video was being uploaded correctly and can be played on youtube. The problem is that I don't have its video_id, so I can't check anything.